# Django: Custom permission has no effect and check within view returns error

Tags: python, django, permissions

I have a generic view (`CreateAPIView`) with a custom permission class `TransactionCreatorIsSenderOrAdmin` but it has no effect on the view at all, even if the permission class contains nothing but `return False`. I think the reason for this is stated in the documentation:

> Also note that the generic views will only check the object-level
>   permissions for views that retrieve a single model instance. If you
>   require object-level filtering of list views, you'll need to filter
>   the queryset separately. See the filtering documentation for more
>   details.

Since I am retrieving more than one model instance, my approach was to do the check within the view itself, inside perform_create, but I get an error and I am not sure why, cause it works without the permission check. Here is the error:

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'date'
Exception Location: .../transactions/api/serializers.py in get_date, line 17
```

Here is my view:

```
class TransactionCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Transaction.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TransactionSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, TransactionCreatorIsSenderOrAdmin]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        amount = self.request.data['amount']
        message = self.request.data['message']
        from_account_iban = self.request.data['from_account']
        from_account_obj = BankAccount.objects.get(iban=from_account_iban)
        to_account_iban = self.request.data['to_account']
        to_account_obj = BankAccount.objects.get(iban=to_account_iban)        
        if from_account_obj.user == self.request.user or self.request.user.is_staff == True:
            serializer.save(amount=Decimal(amount), 
                        from_account=from_account_obj, 
                        to_account=to_account_obj,
                        message=message)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=403)
```

And here is the serializer:

```
class TransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    date = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    from_account = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    to_account = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    slug = serializers.SlugField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_date(self, instance):
        return instance.date.strftime("%B %d %Y")

    def get_from_account(self, instance):
        return instance.from_account.iban

    def get_to_account(self, instance):
        return instance.to_account.iban
```

Comment: **`perform_create`** method not supposed to return anything. Your logic should be within the **`create()`** method of the view

Comment: and also, the exception is not related to the permission class anyway

Comment: If I use `create()` I get `'Request' object has no attribute 'save'`

Comment: oops...it indicated you are doing it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was instead of using the following else statement:

```
return Response(serializer.errors, status=403)
```

using this one:

```
raise PermissionDenied(detail=None, code=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```